# Percentage of overlap between confidence intervals for particular X values between regressions in R

Tags: r

My question might be somehow unintelligible, but I will try to explain further now. But first, this we are working as an example with the dataset `mtcars`. We ggplot now:

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(disp,mpg), colour="blue") + geom_smooth(aes(disp,mpg), method=lm, formula= y~poly(x,3), level=0.95, alpha=0.2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(hp,mpg), colour="green") + geom_smooth(aes(hp,mpg), method=lm, formula= y~poly(x,3), level=0.95, alpha=0.2) +
  labs(x = "Percentage cover (%)", y = "Number of individuals (N)")
```

And we get this plot:

[image]

As you can see, some parts of the confidence limits of both groups overlap. However, **I am NOT interested in the area of overlapping**.

I am **really interested in the percentage of overlap in a line**. In this case, the line is a particular value of X.

Let's take `x = 250`. In the next picture you see two distances (red and pink), each corresponding to the CL of 1 group. There is an overlap between the red and the pink, and I would like to calculate which percentage it is respect both groups. How can I calculate both percentages?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky without some data to exemplify, so, If i understood properly, for a given value in the x-axis, you should have both lower and upper values for the intervals somewhere after fitting the models. then, if a is the upper line and b is the lower one, for each x point you can have (La,Ua) and (Lb,Ub) that is, the lower and upper values for both confident intervals, then the proportion of overlap with respect to the curve a would be 100* (Ub - La) / (Ua - La). In a similar way, the proportion of overlap with respect to b would be 100* (Ua - Lb) / (Ub - Lb). In both cases, '/' is the division sign.

Comment: `mtcars` is the dataset. You can easily load it in R using `data(mtcars)`, as it is part of their own examples.

Comment: Yes I know.... but the data here are confidence intervals of some models fitted to other data...

Answer (score 0):

#### A function gives Percentage of overlap between confidence intervals for particular X values between regressions`,` Overlapping Area`,` corresponding data `and` Final Plot:

```
data("mtcars")
model1=(lm(formula= mpg~poly(disp,3),data =mtcars))
model2=(lm(formula= mpg~poly(hp,3),data = mtcars))
overlapping<-function(data="mtcars",model1,model2, se=T, level=0.95,x.var1="disp",x.var2="hp",n_x=101,given_point=300){
  require(ggplot2)
  data1<-eval(parse(text=data))
  range_x1<-range(eval(parse(text=paste0(data,"$",x.var1))))
  range_x2<-range(eval(parse(text=paste0(data,"$",x.var2))))
  x_range<-c(pmax(range_x1,range_x2)[1],pmin(range_x1,range_x2)[2])

  predictdf.loess <- function(model,  se=T, level=level,x.var="",n_x=101,x_range) {
    xseq<-unique(seq(x_range[1],x_range[2],length.out =  n_x)) 
    newdata<-data.frame(assign (x.var , xseq))
    names(newdata)<-x.var
    pred <- stats::predict(model, newdata , se = se)

    if (se) {
      y = pred$fit
      ci <- pred$se.fit * stats::qt(level / 2 + .5, pred$df)
      ymin = y - ci
      ymax = y + ci
      data.frame(x = xseq, y, ymin, ymax, se = pred$se.fit)
    } else {
      data.frame(x = xseq, y = as.vector(pred))
    }

  }
  smooth1<-predictdf.loess(model=model1,  se=T, level,x.var=x.var1,n_x=101,x_range)
  smooth2<-predictdf.loess(model=model2,  se=T, level,x.var=x.var2,n_x=101,x_range)

  perdict_givenpoint_model1<-predictdf.loess(model=model1,  se=T, level,x.var=x.var1,n_x=101,x_range=c(given_point,given_point))[1,]
  perdict_givenpoint_model2<-predictdf.loess(model=model2,  se=T, level,x.var=x.var2,n_x=101,x_range=c(given_point,given_point))[1,]
  y_givenpoint<-c(pmin(perdict_givenpoint_model1$ymin,perdict_givenpoint_model2$ymin),max_gp<- pmax(perdict_givenpoint_model1$ymax,perdict_givenpoint_model2$ymax))


 overlap_<-function(x=perdict_givenpoint_model1,y=perdict_givenpoint_model2){
   if(x$ymin<=y$ymax & x$ymax>= y$ymin){
   if(x$ymax>y$ymax){ymax=y$ymax}else{ymax=x$ymax}
   if(x$ymin >y$ymin){ymin=x$ymin}else{ymin=y$ymin}
     return(cbind.data.frame(x=x$x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
   } else{
       return(cbind.data.frame(x=x$x,ymin=0,ymax=0))
  }
}

overlap.givenpoint<-overlap_()
percent_gp1<-abs(overlap.givenpoint$ymax-overlap.givenpoint$ymin)/abs(diff(y_givenpoint))*100
  percent_gp<-round(percent_gp1,2)

  condit<-smooth1$ymin<=smooth2$ymax & smooth1$ymax>= smooth2$ymin
  data<-list()
  j<-0
  for (i in which(condit)) {
    if(smooth1$ymax[i]>smooth2$ymax[i]){ymax=smooth2$ymax[i]}else{ymax=smooth1$ymax[i]}
    if(smooth1$ymin[i] >smooth2$ymin[i]){ymin=smooth1$ymin[i]}else{ymin=smooth2$ymin[i]}
    j<-j+1
    data[[j]]<-cbind.data.frame(x=smooth1$x[i],ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax)
  }

  df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(data), nrow=length(data), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  require(bivrp)
  Polygon <- data.frame(x=c(df$X1,rev(df$X1)), y=c(df$X3, rev(df$X2)))
  area<-polygon.area(Polygon)$area
  p1<-ggplot(mtcars) + 
    geom_point(aes(disp,mpg), colour="blue") + geom_smooth(aes(disp,mpg), method=lm, formula= y~poly(x,3), level=0.95, alpha=0.2) +
geom_point(aes(hp,mpg), colour="green") + geom_smooth(aes(hp,mpg), method=lm, formula= y~poly(x,3), level=0.95, alpha=0.2) +
labs(x =paste("Percentage cover",percent_gp, "%")  , y = "Number of individuals (N)")+geom_ribbon(data=df,aes(x=X1,ymin=X3,ymax=X2),fill="gray40")+geom_segment (data=overlap.givenpoint,aes(x=x, xend=x,y=overlap.givenpoint$ymin, yend=overlap.givenpoint$ymax ),colour="red", size=3)
 out<-list(y_givenpoint,overlap.givenpoint,df,area,percent_gp,p1)
  names(out)<-c("Maximum of Y in CI for Given Point","Y in Overlap Area","Overlap Dataset","Ovelap Area","Vline Percentage in Overlap Area by given point","Plot")
  return(out)

}
overlapping(model1=model1,model2=model2)
```

#### For simplicity (Just to calculate Percentage of overlap between confidence intervals for particular X values between regressions in R )

regression models:

```
model1=(lm(formula= mpg~poly(disp,3),data =mtcars))
model2=(lm(formula= mpg~poly(hp,3),data = mtcars))
```

ggplot2 uses this Function `( if n smaller than 1000)` to estimate CI and smoothing line:

```
predictdf.loess <- function(model,  se=T, level=level,x.var="",given.point=300) {
  newdata<-data.frame(assign (x.var , given.point))
  names(newdata)<-x.var
  pred <- stats::predict(model, newdata , se = se)

  if (se) {
    y = pred$fit
    ci <- pred$se.fit * stats::qt(level / 2 + .5, pred$df)
    ymin = y - ci
    ymax = y + ci
    data.frame(x = given.point, y, ymin, ymax, se = pred$se.fit)
  } else {
    data.frame(x = given.point, y = as.vector(pred))
  }

}
```

Y of 0.95 CI For two Models in Given Point:

```
perdict_givenpoint_model1<-predictdf.loess(model=model1,  se=T, level=0.95,x.var="disp",given.poin=300)
perdict_givenpoint_model2<-predictdf.loess(model=model2,  se=T, level=0.95,x.var="hp",given.poin=300)
```

Max and Min of Y in Overlapping Area in Given Point for Both models:

```
y_givenpoint<- c(pmin(perdict_givenpoint_model1$ymin,perdict_givenpoint_model2$ymin),max_gp<- pmax(perdict_givenpoint_model1$ymax,perdict_givenpoint_model2$ymax))
```

Function for Finding Y in Overlapping Area:

```
overlap_<-function(x=perdict_givenpoint_model1,y=perdict_givenpoint_model2){
   if(x$ymin<=y$ymax & x$ymax>= y$ymin){
   if(x$ymax>y$ymax){ymax=y$ymax}else{ymax=x$ymax}
   if(x$ymin >y$ymin){ymin=x$ymin}else{ymin=y$ymin}
     return(cbind.data.frame(x=x$x,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
   } else{
       return(cbind.data.frame(x=x$x,ymin=0,ymax=0))
   }
}
```

Y Of Just Overlapping Area:

```
overlap.givenpoint<-overlap_()
```

Vline Percentage in Overlap Area by Given Point:

```
percent_gp1<-abs(overlap.givenpoint$ymax-overlap.givenpoint$ymin)/abs(diff(y_givenpoint))*100
percent_gp<-round(percent_gp1,2)
```

For just upper regression

```
abs(overlap.givenpoint$ymax-overlap.givenpoint$ymin)/abs(perdict_givenpoint_model1$ymax-perdict_givenpoint_model1$ymin)*100
```

Comment: thanks for the function. I guess `$Vline Percentage in Overlap Area by given point [1] 36.97` shows that the red vertical line represents a 37% of the line where the two CL overlap, but respect the regression placed at the bottom, isn't it? How can you calculate that percentage for the upper regression? With a value of 300, it should be 100%. Can you simplify the function by removing the calculation of the area and showing only those 2 percentages? Anyway, its a fantastic function!!

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, something must be wrong, as if I change the X value to `x = 100`, I get two probabilities, which are 14.41 and 36.32%. With '`x = 100` there is no overlap, so two probabilities should be 0.

Comment: @antecessor  given point supposed to be in the overlapping area, however, I change the code